# Jquery finding firrt element of specific class

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to find a first element having a class "error" applied to it using the below code

```
$('#mainDiv input.error:eq(0)')
```

But the above one working only for input elements only.
How to make this one to work for both input and select elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#mainDiv .error:eq(0)')
```

or

```
$('input.error, select.error', '#mainDiv').first()
```

if you want to find **only** input and select objects

Comment: Actually this class is applied for lot of elements
I want to find first input or select elements having class error

Comment: you're welcome
use this for the first time you use jquery - http://visualjquery.com/